# Does SQL Server Compact support multiple return case parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I know the following is legitimate SQL query, but why this cannot be interpreted in SQL Server Compact? (I'm using SQL Server Compact view)

```
Select  
   Case AStatus  
      When 1 then 'Success', 'AStatus', 'Expected:1'  
      When 0 then 'Faliure', 'AStatus', 'Recived: 0'    
   end
From Statuses  
Where LocalPath= 'c:\Status
```

I get something like:

> Query 1 : There was an error parsing the query [Token line number=3, Token line offset=22, Token in Error=,]

And when writing something like the following it works:

```
Select  
   Case AStatus  
      When 1 then 'Success'
      When 0 then 'Faliure'  
   end
From Statuses  
Where LocalPath= 'c:\Status
```

Comment: Isn't your `CASE` mising and `END`? I also don't think that "multiple return case" is valid at all in mssql...

Comment: No, sorry I missed it when I wrote it again here

Comment: Ok so how can I do somthing like that in mssql in other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's the only valid way to get three columns from case:

```
Select  
    Case AStatus  
        When 1 then 'Success'
        When 0 then 'Faliure'
    END,
    Case AStatus  
        When 1 then 'AStatus'
        When 0 then 'AStatus'
    END,
    Case AStatus  
        When 1 then 'Expected:1'  
        When 0 then 'Recived: 0'  
    END
From Statuses  
Where LocalPath= 'c:\Status'
```

EDIT:
Another way. Not much shorter, but seems more flexible:

```
Select  
    Astatus,
    x.*
From Statuses s
CROSS APPLY (
    select 'Success' as c1,'AStatus' as c2,'Expected:1' as c3 where AStatus=1 union all 
    select 'Failure' ,'AStatus','Recived:0' where AStatus=0
) x
Where LocalPath= 'c:\Status'
```

You get +1 for making me come up with that, I already know where I'll use it :).

Comment: Thanks it is working but, don't we have other way to do so?
Maybe with if statement instead of case?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is missing the `END` Cluase in the `CASE` statement I dont know if this is the only error try this 1st

```
    Select  
    Case AStatus  
    When 1 then 'Success', 'AStatus', 'Expected:1'  
    When 0 then 'Faliure', 'AStatus', 'Recived: 0'  
    END
    From Statuses  
    Where LocalPath= 'c:\Status
```

Comment: I wrote it with end, my mistake, but it still don't know to interpret the multiple column after then